# String of text hex data from text file to real hex

Tags: c++, text, hex, delimiter

I would like to convert lines of hex data stored as text in a text file into hex data stored as char, as below:

Text file contents:

41:89:47:AB

A7:33:1D:AC

Desired format:

```
char Data[NumberOfLinesInFile][HexPerLine];
```

*Note the number of hex per lines are fixed.*

Data should look like:

```
Data[0][0] = 0x41;
Data[0][1] = 0x89;
Data[0][2] = 0x47;
Data[0][3] = 0xAB;
Data[1][0] = 0xA7;
Data[1][1] = 0x33;
Data[1][2] = 0x1D;
Data[1][3] = 0xAC;
```

The problem I have is struggling to get the lines of text to be delimited by ":" and also interpreted as hex, not as ASCII or whatever.

I would be grateful if anyone could offer some insight as to how to go about this. I've been pulling my hair out the last 3 days.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you've been "struggling" for the last three days, you should have source code from at least your most recent effort to post, I'd think. Please [edit] your question to include it, and explain how it's not working as you expect. (Your notation is backward BTW. It should be `Data[Line][1]`, `Data[Line][2]`, etc., where `Line` is a value from `0` to `NumberOfLinesInFile - 1`.)

Comment: I've been struggling to make a start with snippets of code using various functions. What I have would cause more confusion as it's not even close to what I need to get this working. I have nothing substantial in terms of source code to show that would add any benefit to the post above. Thanks for the heads up anyway.

Comment: I realize now about the backward notation, and the "starting from 0" aspect. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll edit the post accordingly.

Comment: This is a personal project. I'm not a college student.

Comment: If anyone has something to offer, such as "try this function" for example, it'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main potential issue is reading a line of hex values separated by colons. The easiest approach seems to read each line into a string, replace the colons by spaces, and read the values after setting the base to hex:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); ) {
    std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ':', ' ');
    std::istringstream in(line);
    std::vector<unsigned char> values{ std::istream_iterator<int>(in >> std::hex),
                                       std::istream_iterator<int>() };
    // now distribute the chars
}
```

Doesn't seem to be too complicated...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!
When you use "in" is that the opened file filestream name?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, adding all the appropriate headers, however, the like beginning "std::vector..." flags a compiler error:

"in C++98 'values' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'".

I am using MinGW 4.8.1-4

Comment: @StuartKerr: It seems you omitted `-std=c++11`. If you don't want to compile using C++11 mode, you can actually use parenthesis: the `>> std::hex` part should prevent the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) which was the primary intend of using braces.

Comment: Thank you!
I didn't have the "-std=c++11" added in the project compiler settings. I added it, however after adding it the same error remains...

Comment: Never mind! I replaced all the settings things with -std=c++11 which stoped the compiler working all together, keeping the previous error standing. I added the -std=c++11 rather than replacing all the settings with it, everything is working now! 

Vielen Dank!